# initialise a virtual machine on a cloud provider and run some custom code on that machine

Tags: java, ruby, amazon-ec2, cloud, rackspace-cloud

I want to initialize a virtual machine on a cloud provider(like Amazon EC2, Rackspace CloudServers, HP Cloud, etc.) and then run some custom code on that machine-- the code may be in Java/Ruby / any other language.

Now, does this mean I have to first launch the server, then install JRE(for java) or other libraries/frameworks required to run the code that I want to be executed on that machine? Is there a quicker way to do this? Maybe a framework that allows me to do this?

One way I thought of is to create a single virtual machine, install JRE on it, then create a server image-- after that I just have to use that image to initialise the virtual machine-- however this leads me to another question- will I have to create a custom image in each cloud provider after creating such a server in each? Or is there a way I can use one server image across many cloud providers?

Answer (score 1):

If your OS is Ubuntu, you could use [CloudInit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit). It can be used to run user-data scripts on first boot.